# Compute improper integral

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck computing the following improper integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} {log x \over x^2}dx $$ 
I tried integration by part and some substituing, but they just don't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: The comparision test tells that it diverges!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x^2}= -\bigl[\frac{\log x+1}{x}\bigr]_0^1=-\bigl[\frac{\log x+1}{x}\bigr]_0^{\epsilon}-\bigl[\frac{\log x+1}{x}\bigr]_{\epsilon}^1$$ The second summand is equal to $-(1-\frac{\log\epsilon+1}{\epsilon})$.

You can verify, for example with L'Hôpital, that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log x+1}{x}=\infty$$

Thus, your integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fact about the improper integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ where the function is unbounded fro example at $a$ ($a\leq x\leq b$). It tells that iif $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}(x-a)^nf(x)=\infty$ for $n\geq1$ then the integral diverges. Now take $a=0, n=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts does work:
Take $u=log(x)$ so that $u'=\frac{1}{x}$
And $v'=\frac{1}{x^2}$ so that $v=-\frac{1}{x}$
Then do the integration from $\varepsilon$ to 1 (with $\varepsilon \in ]0,1]$)
This gives $I_{\varepsilon}=\frac{log(\varepsilon)+1}{\varepsilon}-1$
And so $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} (I_{\varepsilon})=-\infty$